# How do I wire a single pole and a 3-way switch in the same box?

Tags: electrical, switch

I have a 4 gang switch box with one 3-way switch and three single pole switches.  When the 3-way is flipped on, all the other switches can turn their lights on and off.  But when the 3-way is flipped off, none of them work.

I have them wired the same way as a 2 gang switch box with two 3-ways in it that work independently of each other.

All the white wires are tied together.  The red from the 12-3 goes to the 3-way switch.  The black from the incoming power pigtails to all 4 switches, and the black from each fixture goes to each respective switch.

What is wrong?  Can I run three single pole switches and one 3-way off the same power source??  I covered up my walls...

Comment: A diagram of your current wiring would help.

Comment: First glance, it sounds like you have common and a traveler reversed on the 3-way switch. Are you absolutely certain of which line the incoming power is? Otherwise agreed with BMitch:  a diagram and/or annotated picture would help.

Comment: Sounds like the black bringing the power to all four switches is connected to the three way switch instead of the pigtail. If you have a non-contact voltage tester or voltmeter you can test to check this.

Comment: are you saying you WANT the 3way switch to be a master for the other 3 switches, or that it is now, you do not want it that way, and am wondering how to properly wire it?

Comment: so you have: one 12-2 cable from the panel; one 12-3 cable to another 3-way switch; three 12-2 cables to other loads; one 3-way switch, three single pole switches ?